# I can't get the photo metadata

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need help! I have an image, and the problem is that I can't get the data that contain when this image was created and modified:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/world.growtopiagame.com/start.png

but when i use view-source page, i found the date is at the very bottom: view-source:https://s3.amazonaws.com/world.growtopiagame.com/start.png

[here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg6Xc.png)

so my question is how to get the date, i use beautifulsoup

Comment: Can you share the code used ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using BeautifulSoup: that is a parser for html documents. In your case, response is a binary stream. This is one way to get the `Created Date`:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/world.growtopiagame.com/start.png', stream=True)
created_date = str(r.content).split('x00%tEXt')[1].split('+00:00')[0].replace('\\x00', ' ')
modified_date = str(r.content).split('x00%tEXt')[2].split('+00:00')[0].replace('\\x00', ' ')
print(created_date)
print(modified_date)
```

Response in terminal:

```
date:create 2020-09-13T12:56:44
date:modify 2020-09-13T12:56:44
```

Requests documentation can be found at https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/